# How to upload an image using fileupload control and save it in a different location

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, file-upload, razor, image-upload

I have developed a mvc4 razor web application to upload an image of a person and save it in a custom loaction(folder).

it has a fileupload control, a textbox and a button. When i upload an image using file upload control, i need to save it in a custom location like "D:/Employee/ContactImage" and file name should be the value typed in textbox.

here is the code in view

```
<div id="partial">
            @{Html.RenderPartial("WholeSaleUserDetail");}
            @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "WholeSaleTrade", new RouteValueDictionary(new { @class = "mainForm" }), FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {  
                <input name="uploadFile" type="file" id="fileUpload"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Save Image" id="saveImage" />
                <input type="text" id="imageName">

            }
            <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
                <img id="empimage" src="../../Images/no_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
        </div>
```

and here is the code for controller class

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile, string imageName) 
    {
        var j = new ImageJob(uploadFile, "~/Img/resize/" + imageName, new ResizeSettings(300, 300, FitMode.Stretch, "Jpeg"));
        j.Build();
        string imageUrl = PathUtils.GuessVirtualPath(j.FinalPath);

        return Json(imageUrl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

all i need to do here is pass the value of textbox as file name and save the image in the given location.
please help me here..

Comment: what is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: main problem is i cannot pass the textbox value as file name to the controller. in controller class file name should be assigned to the parameter name **"imageName"**

Comment: Have you tried adding name="imageName" to the input?  what about checking the FormCollection to see if it is posted back?

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem with your code, the NAME of the input field need to match with the controller parameter. In your case the html input doesn't have a name, try this.

```
<div id="partial">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("WholeSaleUserDetail");}
        @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "WholeSaleTrade", new RouteValueDictionary(new { @class = "mainForm" }), FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {  
            <input name="uploadFile" type="file" id="fileUpload"/>
            <input type="submit" value="Save Image" id="saveImage" />
            <input type="text" id="imageName" name="uploadFile">

        }
        <div style="width: 200px; height: 200px;">
            <img id="empimage" src="../../Images/no_image.jpg" alt="" /></div>
    </div>
```

and for the controller you can get the filename via the posted file (it has a property)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FileUpload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadFile) 
{
    var j = new ImageJob(uploadFile, "~/Img/resize/" + uploadFile.FileName, new ResizeSettings(300, 300, FitMode.Stretch, "Jpeg"));
    j.Build();
    string imageUrl = PathUtils.GuessVirtualPath(j.FinalPath);

    return Json(imageUrl, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```